# Flutter Sound (Looping)

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, dart

i already made voice recorder using [`flutter_sound`](https://github.com/dooboolab/flutter_sound),

the sound only play once, maybe someone have try to auto loop when it's play ?

```html
@override
  void initState()  {
    if (widget.voiceofer != null) {
      flutterSound.startPlayer(
          '/data/user/0/id.captrue.captrue/app_flutter/${widget.voiceofer}'); 
    }
    super.initState();
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

### Update

using new version of [audioplayers 1.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers) you can use setReleaseMode()

Example:

```
final player = AudioPlayer();

void playSound() async {
    await player.play(AssetSource('sound.mp3'));   
}
void loop() {
    player.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.loop);
}
```

Comment: I noticed that it has a short little silent before looping. Is it expected?

Comment: Do I have to release the player when closing the app while it is still looping?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use **`audioplayers`** as library who has a build in feature for looping audio.

Link: [**audioplayers: ^0.14.0**](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers)

Implementation:

- Create an **AudioCache** instance with the path for your audios (example: "/audio") inside your **Assets** folder.
- Use the Future call `loop` the with name of your file.
- That will create an instance of **AudioPlayer** to handle **Pause** and **Stop**.

Example:

```
static AudioCache musicCache;
static AudioPlayer instance;

void playLoopedMusic() async {
    musicCache = AudioCache(prefix: "audio/");
    instance = await musicCache.loop("bgmusic.mp3");
    // await instance.setVolume(0.5); you can even set the volume
  }

void pauseMusic() {
  if (instance != null) {
    instance.pause();
  }
}
```

Comment: let me try first

Comment: i cant use that, because its a audio from recorder, i record manually from my apps


https://i.imgur.com/UC8ePdi.png

Comment: there's 3 different ways to load the data with that library:

Remote Url: Plays audio from a remote url from the Internet.
Local File: Downloads a file to your device in order to play it from your device.
Local Asset: Play one of the assets bundled with this app. You can follow the example from here: https://github.com/luanpotter/audioplayers/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: but it cant be local asset, because it record from app that i made

i already try to use LocalAsset and LocalFile, but the audio doesnt play
output from the recorder is .aac

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla I would like to ask, is there a way to loop the audio for exact time? what I mean is, I would like to loop  3 minutes audio to play 3 times

Answer (score 2):

"**AudioPlayer**" works well for me with this implementation:

```
//Making sound looping.

final bgAudio = AudioPlayer();

void playBackgroundMusic() {
  bgAudio.play(
    AssetSource('audio/background.mp3'),
  );
  bgAudio.onPlayerComplete.listen((event) {
    bgAudio.play(
      AssetSource('audio/background.mp3'),
    );
  });
```